# Updating complex type with ef code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, complextype

I have a complex type called account, which contains a list of licenses.
Licenses in turn contains a list of domains (a domain is a simple id + url string).

In my repository I have this code

```
    public void SaveLicense(int accountId, License item)
    {

        Account account = GetById(accountId);
        if (account == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        if (item.Id == 0)
        {
            account.Licenses.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            ActiveContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }


        ActiveContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When I try to save an updated License (with modified domains) what happens is that strings belonging straight to the license get updated just fine.

However no domains get updated.

---

I should mention that what I have done is allow the user to add and remove domains in the user interface. Any new domains get id=0 and any deleted domains are simply not in the list.

so what I want is

1. Any domains that are in the list and database and NOT changed - nothing happens
2. Any domains that are in the list and database, but changed in the list - database gets updated
3. Any domains with id=0 should be inserted (added) into database
4. Any domains NOT in the list but that are in the database should be removed

I have played a bit with it with no success but I have a sneaky suspicion that I am doing something wrong in the bigger picture so I would love tips on if I am misunderstanding something design-wise or simply just missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately updating object graphs - entities with other related entities - is a rather difficult task and there is no very sophisticated support from Entity Framework to make it easy.

The problem is that setting the state of an entity to `Modified` (or generally to any other state) only influences the entity that you pass into `DbContext.Entry` and only its scalar properties. It has no effect on its navigation properties and related entities.

You must handle this object graph update manually by loading the entity that is currently stored in the database including the related entities and by merging all changes you have done in the UI into that original graph. Your `else` case could then look like this:

```
//...
else
{
    var licenseInDb = ActiveContext.Licenses.Include(l => l.Domains)
        .SingleOrDefault(l => l.Id == item.Id)

    if (licenseInDb != null)
    {
        // Update the license (only its scalar properties)
        ActiveContext.Entry(licenseInDb).CurrentValus.SetValues(item);

        // Delete domains from DB that have been deleted in UI
        foreach (var domainInDb in licenseInDb.Domains.ToList())
            if (!item.Domains.Any(d => d.Id == domainInDb.Id))
                ActiveContext.Domains.Remove(domainInDb);

        foreach (var domain in item.Domains)
        {
            var domainInDb = licenseInDb.Domains
                .SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == domain.Id);
            if (domainInDb != null)
                // Update existing domains
                ActiveContext.Entry(domainInDb).CurrentValus.SetValues(domain);
            else
                // Insert new domains
                licenseInDb.Domains.Add(domain);
        }
    }
}
ActiveContext.SaveChanges();
//...
```

You can also try out [this project called "GraphDiff"](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) which intends to do this work in a generic way for arbitrary detached object graphs.

The alternative is to track all changes in some custom fields in the UI layer and then evaluate the tracked state changes when the data get posted back to set the appropriate entity states. Because you are in a web application it basically means that you have to track changes in the browser (most likely requiring some Javascript) while the user changes values, adds new items or deletes items. In my opinion this solution is even more difficult to implement.

Comment: Thank you, it was as i feared but at least I now have it confirmed and don't really feel so upset about having to do it that way... if thats how it is :-) However it would be very nice if they could implement some nice support into EF

Comment: @RickardLiljeberg: Yes, you can get used with code like above, but it's only one child collection. It's not funny anymore if you have multiple collections and grandchildren and grandgrand... etc. Btw: You can vote for the feature: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864. But it won't happen before EF 7 (if at all), so probably at least a year to wait.

Comment: I voted happily, I a actually quite surprised to find how limited EF is in that respect.

Comment: It sounds like a joke. This answer really made me question my choice about entity framework vs nhibernate at the first step - we have still a reasonable time for release and I am considering a switch.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to do what you are looking to do. Let me know if you have more questions about the code.

```
public void SaveLicense(License item)
{        
    if (account == null)
    {
        context.Licenses.Add(item);
    }

    else if (item.Id > 0)
           {

               var currentItem = context.Licenses                        
                   .Single(t => t.Id == item.Id);

               context.Entry(currentItem ).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);                    
            }

    ActiveContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```